# how to access List variables in code behind to aspx page

Tags: c#, asp.net, list, repeater, code-behind

I have a public class and a public list.

```
public List<yahoo> yahooRec = new List<yahoo>();

public class yahoo
{

    public string url { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
   public string descripton { get; set; }
}
```

My list get Its values In a foreach loop. I just want to use my list in a repeater

```
<asp:Repeater id="Rep" runat="server">
<ItemTemplate>
 <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%= yahoorec.url %>' Text='<%= yahoorec.title %>' />
<p> <%= yahoorec.description %> </p>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

But it doesnt work.Anybody can help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Rep" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <a href="<%# Eval("url") %>"><%# Eval("title") %></a>
        <p><%# Eval("Url")%> </p>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Or, you can hook into the Rep.ItemDataBound event, find your controls, and populate them in the code-behind.

Answer (score 1):

Use following method in your aspx.cs page

```
Rep.DataSource = yahooRec;
```

and in your aspx page

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Rep" runat="server">
<ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("url") %>'></asp:Label>
    <br />
    <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("title") %>'></asp:Label>
    <br />
    <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("descripton") %>'></asp:Label>
</ItemTemplate>
```